# QVConnect.exe causes out-of-memory error in QlikView using SAP OLAP Connector

Tags: qlikview, sap-bw

I often have to extract months and months of data from SAP Business Warehouse (BW) in one go in QlikView and to do this I use QlikView’s own SAP OLAP Connector.

Rather than have endless repeats of the same SAP Connector Script that changes only by the month and year parameters, I decided to put them inside of a for-next loop as follows:

```
CUSTOM CONNECT TO "Provider=QvSAPOLAPConnector.dll;MSHOST=server1;R3NAME=SBW;GROUP=;CLIENT=100;Log=1;XUserId=ABCDEFG;XPassword=ABCDEFG;";

FOR Month = 1 TO 12
    LET MonthValue = date(addmonths(StartDate, $(Month) - 1),'YYYYMM');

    MyData: 
    LOAD
    *;
    SELECT
    PseudoMDX D (
        Dimensions (
            [0MATERIAL] (),
            [0SALESORG] ()
        ),
        Measures (
            [4VHMY6XTAN8117F8FC78GMG72].[4VHMY7D6CKFG2GI4R0BX0QDMM], // Sales
        ),
        Variables (
            [S_CALM_N] (I = [0CALMONTH].[$(MonthValue)])
        ),
    From (CUBE01/QUERY01));
NEXT
```

Now, this works for relatively small result sets as the memory requirement is within reasonable limits (I monitor the QlikView connector `qvconnect.exe`/`qvconnect64.exe` - 64-bit).

However, I have found that if you are running a large number of loops, even though you are not returning many rows in each , QlikView will often stop loading with an "out-of-memory" message.

How can I avoid this happening without using separate documents with separate scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that it appears that `qvconnect.exe`/`qvconnect64.exe` does not garbage-collect between loops (or indeed `PseudoMDX` statements) so as a result, its memory footprint will steadily increase until your loop/script finishes or your machine runs out of memory.

I am not sure why the process refuses to relinquish its memory, perhaps it is trying to cache some of the dimension values for later use. I have personally seen several server jobs fail because `qvconnect.exe` decided to eat all of 10GiB of memory!

I could not find any official documentation on this subject, but the simple solution is to move the `CUSTOM CONNECT` statement inside of the loop:

```
FOR Month = 1 TO 12
    LET MonthValue = date(addmonths(StartDate, $(Month) - 1),'YYYYMM');

    CUSTOM CONNECT TO "Provider=QvSAPOLAPConnector.dll;MSHOST=server1;R3NAME=SBW;GROUP=;CLIENT=100;Log=1;XUserId=ABCDEFG;XPassword=ABCDEFG;";

    MyData:
    LOAD
    *;
    SELECT
    PseudoMDX D (
        Dimensions (
            [0MATERIAL] (),
            [0SALESORG] ()
        ),
        Measures (
            [4VHMY6XTAN8117F8FC78GMG72].[4VHMY7D6CKFG2GI4R0BX0QDMM], // Sales
        ),
        Variables (
            [S_CALM_N] (I = [0CALMONTH].[$(MonthValue)])
        ),
    From (CUBE01/QUERY01));
NEXT
```

Observing the memory footprint of `qvconnect.exe` whilst the loop executes shows that the memory use increases whilst the data is returned from SAP BW, but it is then freed when the next loop cycle begins.